# how to assign int value to SELECT database string?

Tags: c#, sql, database, integer

I used DataAdapter for use SELECT common to choose rows of Table

```
OleDbDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dayNum = @dayNum", objConnection);  //here dayNum must be equal to 10; dayNum = 10
```

I want assign an integer value to @dayNum

for example

```
int intDay = 10;
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(intDay.ToString(),"@dayNum");
```

but it don't work

how can fix this problem?

Comment: what about  objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayNum",dayNum);

Comment: Where have you defined `objCommand` and how it is related to `objDataAdapter`, looks like you are using command text in `DataAdapter` instead of using existing Command Object, also swap parameter name and value in adding parameter.

Comment: i need use it after WHERE keycode, It's not possible, i guess

Comment: @ali:- I suppose dayNum is the name of the column of your table

Comment: @Habib objCommand it's not important, i just had an example for asaign integer value, I just need a way for asaign int to select string, it was very simple in php language , but i don't know how can i do it in C#

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi yes it's a column of my table that i wan't dayNum that is equal to 10 when i use "WHERE dayNum = 10" it did work but it don't work when "WHERE dayNum = @dayNum"

Comment: @ali:- So the answer below will do what you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.ToString()`. Try this:

```
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayNum",intDay);
```

Comment: function "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.AddWithValue" cannot be called with the given argument list
            argument types are: (int, const char [8])
            object type is: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is the parameter name and the second the value, so:

```
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayNum", intDay); // use the correct type not string
```